# jQuery animate search box border

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i have a question about jQuery animate function. I have a search box and when I click on the search image, it expand by itself and the border appears.

If I click outside this area, the border disappears immediately and is not animated. How do I make sure that the border animates when I click outside the `search-box`?

```
$(".search").click(function () {

    $("#search-box").animate({
        borderWidth: "1px",
        width:"190px"
    },400);

    $(".suche").animate({
        "width" : "300px"
    },400)

    $(".herz").animate({
        "left":"160px"
    },400);

     $(".telefon").animate({
        "left":"160px"
    },400);

    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', function () {
    $("#search-box").animate({
        width: "26px",
        borderWidth:"0px"
    }, 400);

     $(".suche").animate({
        "width" : "150px"
    },400);

       $(".herz").animate({
        "left":"0px"
    },400);

     $(".telefon").animate({
        "left":"0px"
    },400);


});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/fPwB9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fPwB9/6/)

Put the border width animation to the end. If you place it at the beginning, the border disappears before anything else. Look at the demo I provided. I also fixed a part where the div width changes if you click outside the search before clicking in it.

I moved all animation in a callback function to execute after the search box animation completes and then at the end change the border width without animation.

```
$(".search").click(function () {

    $("#search-box").animate({
        borderWidth: "1px",
        width: "190px"
    }, 400, function () {

        $(".suche").animate({
            "width": "300px"
        }, 400)

        $(".herz").animate({
            "left": "160px"
        }, 400);

        $(".telefon").animate({
            "left": "160px"
        }, 400);

    });

    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', function () {

    $("#search-box").animate({
        width: "26px"
    }, 400, function () {
        $(".suche").animate({
            "width": "138px"
        }, 400);

        $(".herz").animate({
            "left": "0px"
        }, 400);

        $(".telefon").animate({
            "left": "0px"
        }, 400, function () {
            $("#search-box").css({
                "borderWidth": "0px"
            });
        });

    });
});
```

edit- I took @Farid Imranov's idea to add the animation for search box click as well to give it consistency. But the answer to your question lies in the callback function on click outside of the search box.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you:

```
$(".search").click(function () {

    $("#search-box").animate({
        borderWidth: "1px",
        width:"190px"
    },400, function(){

        $(".suche").animate({
        "width" : "300px"
    },400)

    $(".herz").animate({
        "left":"160px"
    },400);

     $(".telefon").animate({
        "left":"160px"
    },400);

    });



    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', function () {
    $("#search-box").animate({
        width: "26px",
        borderWidth:"0px"
    }, 400);

     $(".suche").animate({
        "width" : "150px"
    },400);

       $(".herz").animate({
        "left":"0px"
    },400);

     $(".telefon").animate({
        "left":"0px"
    },400);


});
```